# Getting error with generic sort in Delphi Xe2

Tags: delphi, sorting, generics

I hope someone can see what might be wrong here. In Xe2 I have a generic TObjectList that I want to sort. I have a TObjectList that I am sorting in a different place, so I modelled the new code on the old. It all looks correct: ComparePosControl is a non-OOPS function; Rpt is a nested method of a form, TPosCtrl is a simple class.

```
function ComparePosControl(L, R: TPosCtrl): integer;
begin
  result := L.SortNum - R.SortNum;
end;


procedure Rpt(RParent: TWinControl);
begin
  PosCtrls := TObjectList<TPosCtrl>.Create;
  try
    AddPosCtrls(RParent);
    PosCtrls.Sort(TComparer<TPosCtrl>.Construct(ComparePosControl));
```

but I keep getting this error:

[DCC Error] Rputils.pas(1552): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.Generics.Defaults.TComparison' and 'Procedure'

Any ideas?

TIA

Mark

Comment: If you always sort the same way then it may feel cleaner to pass the comparer to the constructor of the list. Also, are you sure you want the list to own and destroy it's members? Seems unlikely given that they are windowed controls. `TList<T>` is perhaps more appropriate.

Comment: In this case there was only one sort over the lifetime of the list, but that is helpful to know.

Comment: Exactly. Since there is only one sort ordering, it can be applied in the constructor.

Comment: Leaving it as is has one benefit: any maintenance programmer will be able to work out the sort quicker if the function is specified at the point of the sort. If the same sort were called from more than one place, I would definitely pass the function to the constructor, because I hate repeating code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change function slightly to match prototype (add **const** modifier):

```
function ComparePosControl(const L, R: TPosCtrl): integer;
```

You may also use anonymous function:

```
PosCtrls.Sort(TComparer<TPosCtrl>.Construct(
  function (const L, R: TPosCtrl): integer;
  begin
    result := L.SortNum - R.SortNum;
  end;
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks! Domestic blindness strikes again. One innocuous word and it was all good.